# New woodean board for a kitchen table

Tags: kitchens, board

I live in Germany and would like to replace the top of a kitchen "table":

[image: board of the kitchen table]

I am thinking of taking a rather inexpensive wood board from birch or beech:

[image: birch massive board]
[image: beeche massive board]

Of course I'd need to paint it. I though of using a lacquer of some sort:

[image: lacquer, silk finish]
[image: lackquer, yacht]

As a second thought, this comes into my mind:

[image: kichen counter]

but I am neither very excited about the way it looks, not how it feels to touch, nor antything.

Questions:

1. Comments on general worktop made of birch or beech?
2. Is birch or beech better?
3. Comments on the two types of lacquers I am think about?
4. What lacquers would you recommend?
5. What's the impact of the lacquers on surfaces that touch all kinds of foods that eventually come to our stomachs?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. Please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why your questions are too many, too broad, and off-topic as product recommendation requests.

Comment: @isherwood: thanks for welcomming and thanks for the tip. Do you think this question is offtopic here?

Comment: I said as much. Please ask just one question per post (the standard across Stack Exchange) and make sure it [fits our guidelines](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We're happy to help.

Comment: There's also a [Woodworking.SE](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions) site that isn't as active, but you can search for types of wood and food safety of finishes.

Comment: I have a birch butcher block dining room table from IKEA. No lacquer or polyurethane. Just mineral oil to keep it from drying out. Like you would do with a cutting board.  I love the look and feel and if the surface gets too dirty you can just sand it down and re-oil. Nothing to strip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a food-safe wood finish, I have had good success using a 1:1 ratio of real pure tung oil and citrus solvent.

My kitchen table is [cypress](http://www.wood-database.com/cypress/), which is much softer than [birch](http://www.wood-database.com/yellow-birch/) or [beech](http://www.wood-database.com/european-beech/), soft enough that I need to lightly sand and refinish the table every year or so.  Working with [tung oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tung_oil) and [citrus solvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limonene) rather than a lacquer makes this task very easy because I don’t have to deal with toxic fumes and a long drying time.

I also have a birch butcher-block countertop with the same finish.  The area closest to the sink has a small amount of water damage after about 5 years. I might consider using the marine finish there.